# Bash - How to use * operator to tell if multiple files exist?

Tags: bash, file, search

I want to write a bash script telling if multiple files exist. My attempt is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=*.dat

for d in $(find ~/Desktop/Results/ -maxdepth 4 -type d)
do
    echo $d
    cd $d 
    if [ -f "$FILE" ]; then
        echo "$FILE exists."
    fi

cd ~/Desktop/Results
done
```

My problem is now, that the * Operator does not work with the FILE variable. Do you know how to make it work that all existing *.dat files are echoed like shown in the code?

Comment: Why not just use find "~/Desktop/Results/$FILE" -maxdepth 4 -type d ?

Comment: @RamanSailopal That does not work, it says file does not exist...

Comment: Try find "~/Desktop/Results" -maxdepth 4 -type d -name "$FIL"

Comment: You realize that the value of `FILE` doesn't change in your loop, right?

Comment: If you want to list all files with a `.dat` extension in a directory tree.... `find ~/Desktop/Results -maxdepth 4 -name "*.dat"`

Comment: @Armani42 : What is a "multiple file"? Do you mean several occurances of a certain name in different directories?

Comment: why on earth do you use a for loop on the result of `find` instead of using `-exec`? Your method will fail if there are files with new lines in the names

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```
find ~/Desktop/Result -name '*.dat' -type f
```

This writes to stdou all files where the name ends in `.dat`. If you also interested in directories ending in `.dat`, omit the `-type f`.

Answer (score 0):

This should achieve what you wanted :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

files="*.dat"

shopt -s nullglob
for d in $(find ~/Desktop/Results/ -maxdepth 4 -type d)
do
    cd $d 
    glob=($files)
    if [ ${#glob[@]} != 0 ]; then
        echo $d
        echo "${glob[*]} exists."
    fi
done

cd ~/Desktop/Results
```